# String Input in C++

Tags: c++, string

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int a,b;
  cin>>a;
  cin>>b;
  cout<<" "<<endl;
  string c;
  getline(cin,c);
  int i=1;
  int s=0;
  while(c[i]!='\0')
  {
    if(c[i]=='1')
    {
      s+=a;
      a=a*a;
      i++;
    }
    else
    {
      a=a*a;
      i++;
    }  
  }
  int r=s%b;
  cout<<r;
  return 0;
}
```

here in this code i want to take input in the form
5 100
101
but the code takes input in the form 
5 100 101
as soon as i input the values of a,b integer and press enter to take the input of string it just terminates the code
can someone explain why is this happening and how can i avoid it

Comment: The `Enter` key you use to end the input of the numbers is left in the buffer as a newline for the `getline` call to read. You need to [ignore](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The getline command only looks in one line and will stop looking after the newline on the first line. When you press enter, a newline is inserted, so getline will stop looking. To look in two lines and then combine the two lines into one string, you can do the following

```
  string c;
  string d;
  getline(cin, c);
  getline(cin, d);
  c = c + d;
```

An alternative is to use what someprogrammerdude suggested in his comment, which is to ignore the newline.

Note: You may need to add a space between the two lines in your specific example if you want a space between 100 and 101.

```
  string c;
  string d;
  getline(cin, c);
  c += " ";
  getline(cin, d);
  c = c + d;
```